# php sum the values seperated by special character

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I need to sum the result set values separated by "|" inside the loop eg. set of values 10|2, 6|2, 8|1 should result in 24|5.

here is my code:

```
<?php
 $fromdate="2016-03-31";
 $todate="2016-03-31";
 $TAG="1";
 $con = mysqli_connect("XXXXX","XX","XXX","XXX");
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "CALL sp_Android_Online_Dashboard('$fromdate', '$todate','$TAG')") or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());
 $Totfiles = 0;
 $file_minutes = 0;
 $Tot_minutes=0;
 $Pending=0;
 while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))) 
 {
     $Totfiles +=$row["Totfiles"];
     $file_minutes +=$row["file_minutes"];
     $Pending =str_replace(array("/"),"|",$row["Pending"]); //need to sum all the values separated by "|"
     $Tot_minutes +=$row["Tot_minutes"];
 }
$response["Details"]['Totfiles'] = $Totfiles;
$response["Details"]['file_minutes'] = $file_minutes;
$response["Details"]['Pending'] = $Pending;
$response["Details"]['Tot_minutes'] = $Tot_minutes;
echo json_encode($response);      
?>

$row["Pending"] contains the values which are to be summed
```

result am getting now,

```
"Pending":"16|9"
"Pending":"11|3"
"Pending":"6|2"
```

my expected result,

```
"Pending":"33|14"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are aiming at i think, you make an array first containing 2 values, on each iteration through the loop you add the new values to them and at the end you can implode it into a string again

```
// Start with an array containing 0 twice
$Totalpending = [0,0];
 while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))) 
 {
     // On each loop we add the left value to the first value in the array and the right value to the second value in the array
     $tmp = explode("|", $row['Pending']);
     $Totalpending[0] += $tmp[0];
     $Totalpending[1] += $tmp[1];

     $Totfiles +=$row["Totfiles"];
     $file_minutes +=$row["file_minutes"];
     $Pending =str_replace(array("/"),"|",$row["Pending"]); //need to sum all the values separated by "|"
     $Tot_minutes +=$row["Tot_minutes"];
 }
// if you want to format the values in the same way again, although an array is much easier to handle, but it's up to you.
$stringTotalpending = implode('|',$Totalpending);
```

the string value you want will then be in `$stringTotalpending`

Answer (score 0):

So Firstly, we need to explode the values from `$row["Pending"]`.

```
$arr = explode("|", $row["Pending"]);
```

Now use a loop to add those two numbers:

```
$temp = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    $temp += (int) $arr[$i];
}
```

Now the `$temp` would contain the result.

As simple as that.

<sub>And also as a side note, your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection attacks.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What about evaling the same string with '|' replaced by '+' ?

```
eval('$result = ' . str_replace('|', '+', preg_replace('/[^0-9|]/', '', $row["Pending"])) . ';');
echo "$result\n";
```

Note preg_replace() to sanitize input. Can be avoided if input is already sanitized